# 6 Wire Stepper motor with only 1 Center tap

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, coil

I salvaged a stepper motor from an old computer i had laying around, it has 6 wires. The problem is that when i try and measure the resistance between the wires i only get 1 Center tap where the resistance is halved. All other 5 wires are connected to the same coil. I thought this was weird so i opened the motor and tried measuring the resistance directly from the leads on the board, but i got the same result as before.
Could it be that i have a 6 wire stepper motor with only 1 coil? Because all of the leads are connected in some way i have tried connecting them all (2 at a time) to an led, while turning the motor around, and the did lit up every time/combination i tried. Does anyone know what type of motor i have, because i have never seen one like this before. The yellow wire is the center wire (15 ohm, connected with all other 5 wires) the rest is 29,8 ohm (connected 1 by 1 except the yellow of course):[image]

Comment: connect a supply across common, and each phase in turn, and see how far it steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting, looks like what you have there is a 5-phase STAR, 6 cable model like this one.

[image]

[image]

[DRIVER CHIP HERE](http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/70/272058_DS.pdf)

Comment: Yes that seems to be the case, but i have never heard of them before. Do you know if it requires a special driver to run it? Or can i modify it to use one of the more common drivers, which i probably have laying around. Any good sources to research this?

Comment: Ya was news to me too. Best I found so far was this page... http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/step/types.html

Comment: And the 6 load ones seem even less common. Pentagon configuration seems more prevalent for whatever reason.

Comment: Found a driver IC here. http://pdf.datasheetcatalog.com/datasheets/70/272058_DS.pdf

Answer (score -1):

You probably don't need a special driver -> the driving sequency for a typical 5/6 wire motor should work, adapted for your motor, obviously.

finding the windings' sequence would be tricky.